# Foreach looping only once

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a problem with PHP code : I have been using PHP to generate static HTML files (via fopen/fwrite) depending on some SQL requests (among others) and I have a problem with a foreach loop:

```
$maincats = array('/boutique' => 'TOUS LES OBJETS',
                    '/boutique/nouveautes' => 'NOUVEATES',
                    '/boutique/luminaires' => 'LUMINAIRES',
                    '/boutique/assises' => 'ASSISES',
                    '/boutique/rangements' => 'RANGEMENT',
                    '/boutique/objets-deco' => 'OBJETS DECO',
                    '/boutique/tables' => 'TABLES',
                    '/boutique/art-de-la-table' => 'ARTS DE LA TABLE',
                    '/boutique/high-tech' => 'HIGH-TECH',
                    '/boutique/enfants' => 'ENFANT');

    $page .= '
<div id="menuWrap">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($maincats as $url => $name);
    {
        $i++;
        $page .= '
        <li><a ';
        $page .= 'href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
    }
```

I tried print_r before the foreach, I can see ALL the elements of the array (it works just fine). But every time I execute this the $page only contains ONE `<li>` , the last item of the array, and `$i = 1`. I can't think of what I am doing wrong.
Anyone has an idea where that comes from?

Comment: You have a semicolon on the foreach line, I would start by removing that.

Comment: remove `;` after `foreach([...])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove **;** from

```
foreach ($maincats as $url => $name);
```

Comment: Ok thanks guys... My bad ! I didn't see it although I went through my code a couple times.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;`

**Wrong code**

```
 foreach ($maincats as $url => $name);
    {
```

**Correct code**

```
 foreach ($maincats as $url => $name)
    {
```